# Let $a_n$ be a sequence of nonnegative numbers such that $a_n \rightarrow b$. Then, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{(a_{n+1})^{n+1}}{(a_n)^n}$ =?

Tags: real-analysis

As the title says, I would like to evaluate the following limit given that $a_n \rightarrow b < \infty$: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{(a_{n+1})^{n+1}}{(a_n)^n}$ (I am assuming that the limit would evaluate to $b$.)

If $n$ is taken sufficiently large enough, then $|a_n - b|< \epsilon$. Hence, $a_n \in (b-\epsilon, b+\epsilon)$. Hence,

\begin{align*}
\frac{(a_{n+1})^{n+1}}{(a_n)^n} &= a_{n+1}\frac{(a_{n+1})^n}{(a_n)^n} \\
&= a_{n+1} \frac{(b+\epsilon)^n}{(b-\epsilon)^n} \\
&= a_{n+1} \frac{b^n + \binom{n}{1} b^{n-1}\epsilon + \cdots + \binom{n}{n} \epsilon^n}{b^n - \binom{n}{1} b^{n-1}\epsilon + \cdots + (-1)^n\binom{n}{n} \epsilon^n}
\end{align*}

I am tempted to say that since $b$ term dominates $\epsilon$ terms, the fraction is really equivalent to $\frac{b^n}{b^n}$, but how do I rigorously prove it?

---

**EDIT:**

Note that:
$$\infty = \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{b+\frac{1}{m}}{b-\frac{1}{m}}\right)^n \neq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{b+\frac{1}{m}}{b-\frac{1}{m}}\right)^n = 1$$

Is what I have written above a correct approach to the problem?

---

**EDIT:**
Original motivation of the problem:

> Suppose $\mu$ is a positive measure on $X, \mu(X) < \infty, f \in L^\infty(\mu),||f||_\infty > 0, \text{and}$
> $$a_n = \int_X|f|^n\,d\mu~~~~~(n=1,2,3,...).$$
> prove that$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = ||f||_\infty$$

Comment: As $n\to \infty $  , $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: Isn't it the other way around? as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @LeeMosher I have been thinking for a while, but not sure how to think. Can you provide me a direction how to approach this problem?

Comment: @paulpogba not exactly. $a_n$ approaches $b$ as $n\to \infty$ and as you are writing it as $b\pm \epsilon$ then $\epsilon \to 0$

Comment: @LeeMosher Now, the answer is found. However, I am interested in hearing your approach to the problem. What point of convergence property are you highlighting at?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I misread the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $a_n:=1+\frac 1{2n}(1-(-1)^n)$, i.e. $a_{2n}=1$ and $a_{2n+1}=1+\frac 1n$. Then the quantity of interest is $A_n:=\frac{a_{n+1}^{n+1}}{a_{n}^{n}}$ has two subsequences converging to $e$ and $1/e$, respectively for even and odd values of $n$. Thus $\lim_{n\to+\infty} A_n$ may not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Giulio.  Let
$$
a_n = 1 + \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}
$$
Then $a_{n+1}^{n+1}/a_n^{n}$ has subsequences converging to $0$ and to $+\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach revealing why the limit need not always exist and how we can evaluate the limit given the sequence $a_n$.

$$\frac{(a_{n+1})^{n+1}}{(a_n)^n} =a_{n+1}\left[1+\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1\right)\right]^n $$
$$=a_{n+1}\left[1+\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1\right)\right]^{\frac{1}{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1}(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-1)(n)}$$

Therefore, $\frac{(a_{n+1})^{n+1}}{(a_n)^n}$ approaches
$$b\exp\left(\frac{L}{b}\right)$$
where $$L=\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} {(a_{n+1}-a_n)n}$$ assuming it exists.
Clearly we cannot decide on $L$ as it can be $0$ or $\infty$ or may not exist.

Further, you cannot conclude out of temptation (referring your question) because the limit in the fraction is of form $1^{\infty}$.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was wondering about.

Comment: Not that I followed that, but $b\exp(L/b)$ can't be right unless $L=0$. Because the Cesaro-Stolz theorem shows that if $\lim a_{n+1}^{n+1}/a_n^n=\alpha$ then $\lim a_n=\alpha$.

Comment: Yes you are right. If $\frac{(a_{n+1})^{n+1}}{(a_n)^n}$ has a limit, then $L=0$ as $L$ can take value either infinity or zero ($L$ has to exist as the whole limit exists and so $L=0$).